# AHK's Run is not saving the correct PID

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script that is supposed to open a new incognito window, display the pid, then close the incognito window. However the pid saved from `Run` doesn't match windowSpy's pid.

Here's the script:

```
Global ChromeExe := "C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
!c::LaunchSite()

; Launch localhost, show the pid then close it.
LaunchSite(){
  Run, %ChromeExe% -incognito http://localhost,,,LocalPID
  MsgBox, LocalPID: %LocalPID%
  WinClose, ahk_pid %LocalPID%
}
```

***Why does the PID saved from Run not match the PID in WindowSpy?***

An example of this mismatch is LocalPID: 14648; WindowSpy: 13560.

*Edit: When I hard code the WindowSpy PID (13560) the window closes as expected.*

Comment: Look in the Details tab column PID of the Task Manager whether the PIDs displayed in MsgBox and WindowSpy are indeed new and belong to the new process or were there before.

Comment: Chrome is likely to generate 3 or 4 PIDs per tab, plus its own 'mother app' PID & page-independent sub-processes. Here's a pic of merely the first few on Safari - this goes on for pages & pages with 30 tabs open - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMpgm.png - it is unimportant to this issue that I'm on a different browser & OS; this is how PIDs are allocated, one to each individual process within a 'global app'.